# AmbientDataContext is not properly initialised

Tags: content-delivery, experience-manager

I have a DD4T website, and I am struggling to get Tridion Experience Manager 2012 Session Preview working correctly. After editing a bit of content on the page, when i hit "Finish Editing", the page commits the edit, refreshes itself and "loses" the text I just edited. I can only see the updated page by navigating away and coming back to the page (hence it seems the commit to the broker database is working fine - it's just the the "Session Preview" that isn't!).

When i look at the logs returned (by both staging site and session-preview web service), the following is the only error i receive in both logs:
**"AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised"**

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue? any particular .config, .jar, or .xml files required? What configuration do i need to check? how do you even test the ambient data framework is "correctly initialised"??

**NOTE:** I have already followed (and satisfied all steps) in the following blog post: http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience this warning (no 'Error' right?) can safely be ignored. It's followed by something along the lines of: setting current ambient data context... Did you turn of cache? If not, can you try it without any caching?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the Filter (for java) or the HttpModule (for .net) are correctly configured in your web.xml/web.config

These will be the ones that makes the Ambient Data Context available for your websites

.Net (web.config):

```
<add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" />
```

Java (web.xml):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The latter option actually was missing at some point in my project, and that caused some similiar issues.

Answer (score 9):

I was troubleshooting an Experience Manager installation today, and had the same symptoms, but no obvious other error messages. In the end the issue was not having correct Host element(s) set up in the **cd_dynamic_conf.xml** of the staging website, corresponding to the staging website domain and port. Check you have something like:

```
<Publication Id="3">
    <Host Domain="staging.mysite.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/fr"/>
</Publication>
```

Note I also had the error message you mention, but session preview works fine, so I dont think this error is related to your problem.

Comment: I think I see this error occur ONCE per session - it looks like the first time Tridion tries to load the Ambient Framework the current claimstore is `null` - which is correct -  and Tridion logs it as an error, which I don't think it's correct, because it's just not initialized yet.

Comment: Thanks Will, i checked the cd_dynamic_config and it seems correct. Anyways given that you got the same error and session preview still worked for you indicates that the issue lies elsewhere. i'll keep digging. Thanks!

Comment: @NunoLinhares I remember the same from setting up UGC, but I think that was a warning rather than an error.